# How to get this plugin working for the homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

first of all I am no programmer, but I can follow instructions ;-)
I have downloaded a wordpress plugin called TF Social share.
Now I want this social buttons working also on my homepage, so I added the custom code `<?php if(function_exists('kc_add_social_share')) kc_add_social_share(); ?>` in my header. 
Now the problem is when someone wants to like my homepage that they like my first article. Somehow this plugin uses my latest articles on the homepage in stead of the homepage itself. This maybe because the theme has a static homepage itself in stead of the ones that are being used in the settings area?
Does a simpel line of extra code work in my header maybe?
Any help would be appreciated.
btw here is the [website](http://www.ipadabonnement4u.nl)

And here the [article that is being used](http://www.ipadabonnement4u.nl/ipad-mini-deze-zomer-leverbaar/) with the social buttons on the homepage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that plugin is mostly to be used for displaying on each page that has an article or blog post but the creator has a hosted FAQ and answers questions there that may be helpful: http://www.searchtechword.com/2012/01/faq-for-wordpress-plugin-twitter-facebook-google-plus-one-social-share/

One user, Jimmy, says: "Okay, I figured it out. In TF Social Share settings:

Show button in these pages: I unchecked Home.

It got rid of that “Tweet” word and solved my issue. **I guess whichever page is your Post Excerpt page is considered your Home page!** [emphasis mine] Hope this helps others!!!"

It sounds like he may have been having the same issue (but I don't see an original post of what the problem was.)

If playing with the settings in the WordPress controls doesn't work, the author of the plugin invites questions here: http://www.searchtechword.com/about-searchtechword/

Answer (score 1):

I would make the Facebook Like Button from Facebook API... its just following steps as well....

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/